# Reading 2d arrays into a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I searched stackoverflow but could not find an answer to this specific question. Sorry if it is a naive question, I am a newbie to python.

I have several 2d arrays (or lists) that I would like to read into a 3d array (list) in python. In Matlab, I can simply do

```
 for i=1:N
    # read 2d array "a"
    newarray(:,:,i)=a(:,:) 
 end
```

so newarray is a 3d array with "a" being the 2d slices arranged along the 3rd dimension.

Is there a simple way to do this in python?

Edit: I am currently trying the following:

```
 for file in files:     
   img=mpimg.imread(file)
   newarray=np.array(0.289*cropimg[:,:,0]+0.5870*cropimg[:,:,1]+0.1140*cropimg[:,:,2])
   i=i+1
```

I tried `newarray[:,:,i]` and it gives me an error

```
NameError: name 'newarray' is not defined
```

Seems like I have to define newarray as a numpy array? Not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these arrays, like `numpy.ndarray` or `array.array`, or are they lists?

Comment: @abarnert I am trying to read in several image files into a 3d array.     `for file in files:     
    img=mpimg.imread(file)
    cropimg=img[100:600,200:960]
  newarray=np.array(0.289*cropimg[:,:,0]+0.5870*cropimg[:,:,1]+0.1140*cropimg[:,:,2])
    i=i+1`     but I have tried `newarray[:,:,i]` and it gives me an error

Comment: @MPy: Describing a bit of your code and then saying "gives me an error" doesn't allow anyone to debug your code. Give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the exception's traceback.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with MATLAB, translating that into using [NumPy](http://www.scipy.org/index.html) is fairly straightforward.

Lets say you have a couple arrays

```
a = np.eye(3)
b = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))

print(a)
# [[ 1.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.]]

print(b)
# [[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]
#  [6 7 8]]
```

If you simply want to put them into another dimension, pass them both to the array constructor in an iterable (e.g. a list) like so:

```
x = np.array([a, b])
print(x)
# [[[ 1.  0.  0.]
#   [ 0.  1.  0.]
#   [ 0.  0.  1.]]
# 
#  [[ 0.  1.  2.]
#   [ 3.  4.  5.]
#   [ 6.  7.  8.]]]
```

Numpy is smart enough to recognize the arrays are all the same size and creates a new dimension to hold it all.

```
print(x.shape)
# (2, 3, 3)
```

You can loop through it, but if you want to apply the same operations to it across some dimensions, I would **strongly suggest you use broadcasting so that NumPy can vectorize the operation** and it runs a whole lot faster.

For example, across one dimension, lets multiply one slice by 2, another by 3. (If it's not a pure scalar, we need to reshape the array to the same number of dimensions to broadcast, then the size on each needs to either match the array or be 1). *Note that I'm working along the 0th axis, your image is probably different. I don't have a handy image to load up to toy with*

```
y = x * np.array([2, 3]).reshape((2, 1, 1))
print(y)
#[[[  2.   0.   0.]
#  [  0.   2.   0.]
#  [  0.   0.   2.]]
#
# [[  0.   3.   6.]
#  [  9.  12.  15.]
#  [ 18.  21.  24.]]]
```

Then we can add them up

```
z = np.sum(y, axis=0)
print(z)
#[[  2.   3.   6.]
# [  9.  14.  15.]
# [ 18.  21.  26.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays, you can translate almost directly from Matlab:

```
for i in range(1, N+1):
    # read 2d array "a"
    newarray[:, :, i] = a[:, :]
```

Of course you'd probably want to use `range(N)`, because arrays use 0-based indexing. And obviously you're going to need to pre-create `newarray` in some way, just as you'd have to in Matlab, but you can translate that pretty directly too. (Look up the `zeros` function if you're not sure how.)

---

If you're using lists, you can't do this directly—but you probably don't want to anyway. A better solution would be to build up a list of 2D lists on the fly:

```
newarray = []
for i in range(N):
    # read 2d list of lists "a"
    newarray.append(a)
```

Or, more simply:

```
newarray = [read_next_2d_list_of_lists() for i in range(N)]
```

Or, even better, make that `read` function a generator, then just:

```
newarray = list(read_next_2d_list_of_lists())
```

If you want to transpose the order of the axes, you can use the `zip` function for that.